# Accessing Files in a SharePoint Site via Graph: Bad Request

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

The documentation for using the MS Graph 1.0 API for accessing SharePoint files from libraries seems clear enough, if a bit indirect.  My understanding is that I should be able to access the top level item of a library (and then its children via `/children`) by the following url scheme:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<my-tenant>.sharepoint.com:/sites/my-test-site:/drive/root
```

But I am only getting back an error telling me the Url is invalid:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Url specified is invalid.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "08bb72aa-f3be-4df0-b253-dacc4a8fe390",
      "date": "2019-07-08T16:38:07"
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried a few other url formats as well, such as specifying the drive specifically by Id `/drives/<driveId>/root` but had the same luck.  I'm sure I am misunderstanding something.  I'm using the "Path" format (:/sites/path-to-site:/ in the API because it is more natural than going and fetching an Id for everything I need to query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need provide global Id of the site you want to access (global Id is `<hostName>,<siteCollectionId>,<siteId>`).To get the global id, in you test, we can use this.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<my-tenant>.sharepoint.com:/sites/my-test-site:/
```

And below API gives us a list of files on a specified site's default drive:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<hostName>,<siteCollectionId>,<siteId>/drive/root/children
```

If you want to access files on a specific list, all you need is the id of the list:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<hostName>,<siteCollectionId>,<siteId>/lists/<listId>/drive/root/children
```